# Python, dict, ошибка итерации

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари

При переборе словаря происходит ошибка:

```
    for i,s in load.items():
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

Сам код:

```
for i,s in load.items():   <---Здес проблема
    for a,o in load2.items():
        if i == a:
            load.pop(i)# Сравнение и доление похожих ключей
for i,a in load.items():
    load2[i] = a
with open("copi_vocabu.data","wb") as f:
    picle.dump(load2,f)
```

не понимаю что нитак делаю

Comment: Ну пишет же, что вы изменяете размер `pop()` словаря при прохождении по нему. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11941817/how-to-avoid-runtimeerror-dictionary-changed-size-during-iteration-error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение уже есть, нужно только погуглить.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11941817/how-to-avoid-runtimeerror-dictionary-changed-size-during-iteration-error

Используйте keys() вместо items(), вам все равно значения не нужны.

Comment: По мне лучше делать фильтры вместо этих попов